# Express.js - Image only renders on one page

Tags: javascript, html, image, express, pug

I'm trying to make an image appear on multiple pages using Pug and Express.
But I've been  running into some trouble.

The image should be rendered on the page on the routes '/', 'data', 'update'. It is successfully rendered on the root '/', but afterwards, disappears from the Sources folder.

In app.js I have this middleware about all my route-handlers:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

In the public folder I also have the file styles.css which renders fine on the other pages.

I fixed it by putting

```
  img(src="/image.jpg")
```

instead of

```
   img(src="image.jpg)
```

Anybody know why that is?

Comment: Relative urls in your template? Just turn them into static ones.

Answer (score 1):

Lets imagine you got the following url on your page (that loads an image or whatever):

```
  <img src="image.jpg" />
```

Now if that template is on the main page, e.g. `http://example.com/`, it will point to `http://example.com/image.jpg` which will hit the express static route and everything is fine. Now you visit `http://example.com/something`, and as tze image url us relative, it will point to `http://example.com/something/image.jpg`. And that file does not exist. Now if you change the image to:

```
  <img src="/image.jpg" />
```

It will be relative to the pages *root* (`http://example.com`) and therefore it will always work.