# Images not loading on certain EJS pages - Node.js, Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am currently working on a webapp with Node.js, Express, EJS, Passport, etc... And I am having a hard time getting my images to load on certain pages of my webapp. I am using the same exact `img` tags as the pages that are loading the images which is:

```
<img src="./public/images/ResConnectBanner.png" width="50%" height="50%" alt="ResConnect Logo"/>
```

I also noticed that the pages that the images aren't loading on are the same "distance" away from the index.ejs page. Here is a sitemap to show you what I mean:

```
Index
|
|__Login/Register
    |
    |__Home
        |
        |__Community Mapping
        |   |
        |   |__View Maps
        |       |
        |       |__View Individual Map (BANNER DOES NOT LOAD)
        |
        |__Roommate Management
            |
            |__View Agreements
                |
                |__View Individual Agreement (BANNER DOES NOT LOAD)
```

Here is the the express routing code that I have in my server.js file that loads the images on the pages that are working:

```
var express  = require('express');
var session  = require('express-session');
var favicon = require('express-favicon');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 1848;

var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');


require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

app.use('/public/images/', express.static('./public/images'));

app.use(favicon(__dirname + './public/favicon.ico'));
```

I'm not sure if this question makes sense, but if you need clarification or have questions, please let me know! Thanks so much in advance for any tips or help! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705304/express-js-image-only-renders-on-one-page/49705859#49705859 <- an exact duplicate of your question :)

Comment: @JonasW. ah that's embarrassing. Thank you!

Comment: glad to help :)